# .NET and/or Web Service-accessible Object Manager with Security

Tags: c#, .net, orm, data-modeling

I currently use Microsoft CRM for a lot of development but am questioning if there is a better toolset for certain applications.  One of the strengths with MS CRM is being able to create objects, relate them and add attributes.  On top of this you have security and searching.  There are other features such as UI, etc but I am keen to write an application that doesn't use the CRM user interface but has strong data modelling, manages the database layer and is supported, flexible and rapid in model development -- all characteristics of MS CRM.  I have looked at ADO.NET dynamic data entities but wasn't a big fan.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give a shot to Fluent nHibernate, I just love it.
Simple , easy and extremely fast to use.

We have been using it in couple of project and also migrated a big project on this.

Take a look 
http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/